# Batch script for loop and :prompt

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I am trying to create a batch script with the following purpose: backing up database and put it on another server. However I would like it in a for loop so you can put 10 databases in databases.txt and just run the script and add a line to databases.txt if you need another database backed up.

So databases.txt =

```
db1
db2
db3
db4
db5
db6
```

I want to decide per database if I think its neccesary to download the database or skip that specific one with a prompt. What I came up with is following:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in (databases.txt) do (
    :PROMPT
       SET /P needbackup="Do you need to download the backup for %%a: (Y/[N])?
       IF /I "!needbackup!" NEQ "Y" GOTO END
          echo CURRENTLY COPYING DB FROM %%a TO A SQL FILE

    :END
    endlocal
)
```

The problem is that once I filled in for example N, to skip downloading the first database, the variable `needbackup` is stuck at N while I want to be prompted again by the script.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: you can use GOTO inside brackets/for body because you'll break their context. Put the code into a subroutine and call it inside the FOR.

Comment: Excuse me, i'm not that familiar with batch scripting, mind typing an example?

Comment: check the part with the subroutines here: https://ss64.com/nt/call.html.

Comment: Instead of skipping something when a certain condition is met, simply negate the condition and do execute the conditional part, so you do no longer need labels and `goto`…

Comment: @npocmaka, I looked some stuff up and now I got it working exactly how I wanted. Thank you for pointing me in the right direction :)!

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming this is the ad-hoc script
and the number of DB to backup is fairly constant around 10?

what if you dropped for loop and used 'choice' command?
this way you don't have go y/n one by one just select which DB you need in any order.
for example:

```
@echo off

:begin
echo.
echo select db:
echo 1) db1
echo 2) db2
echo 3) db3
echo 4) db4
echo 5) db5
echo 6) db6
echo 7) db7
echo 8) db8
echo 9) db9
echo 10) db10
echo.

set /p db=choose db: 
if "%db%"=="1" goto  db1
if "%db%"=="2" goto  db2
if "%db%"=="3" goto  db3
if "%db%"=="4" goto  db4
if "%db%"=="5" goto  db5
if "%db%"=="6" goto  db6
if "%db%"=="7" goto  db7
if "%db%"=="8" goto  db8
if "%db%"=="9" goto  db9
if "%db%"=="10" goto db10

echo choose an option:
goto begin

:db1
echo CURRENTLY COPYING DB FROM 1 TO A SQL FILE
goto begin
 
:db2
echo CURRENTLY COPYING DB FROM 2 TO A SQL FILE
goto begin
 
:db3
echo CURRENTLY COPYING DB FROM 3 TO A SQL FILE
goto begin
 
:db4
echo CURRENTLY COPYING DB FROM 4 TO A SQL FILE
goto begin

:db5
echo CURRENTLY COPYING DB FROM 5 TO A SQL FILE
goto begin

:db6
echo CURRENTLY COPYING DB FROM 6 TO A SQL FILE
goto begin

:db7
echo CURRENTLY COPYING DB FROM 7 TO A SQL FILE
goto begin

:db8
echo CURRENTLY COPYING DB FROM 8 TO A SQL FILE
goto begin

:db9
echo CURRENTLY COPYING DB FROM 9 TO A SQL FILE
goto begin

:db10
echo CURRENTLY COPYING DB FROM 10 TO A SQL FILE
goto begin
```

output:

```
select db:
1) db1
2) db2
3) db3
4) db4
5) db5
6) db6
7) db7
8) db8
9) db9
10) db10

choose db: 9
CURRENTLY COPYING DB FROM 9 TO A SQL FILE

select db:
1) db1
2) db2
3) db3
4) db4
5) db5
6) db6
7) db7
8) db8
9) db9
10) db10

choose db: 2
CURRENTLY COPYING DB FROM 2 TO A SQL FILE

select db:
1) db1
2) db2
3) db3
4) db4
5) db5
6) db6
7) db7
8) db8
9) db9
10) db10
```